# How to register a controller with parameterized constructor, programatically? (in Castle Windsor - ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, configuration, controller, castle-windsor, global-asax

I want to register controllers programatically in **Global.asax.cs**.
with MvcContrib.Castle.WindsorControllerFactory

```
private static IWindsorContainer _Container;

protected virtual void InitializeWindsor()
        {
            try
            {
                if (_Container == null)
                {
                    _Container = new WindsorContainer();
                    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MvcContrib.Castle.WindsorControllerFactory(_Container));

                    RegisterActiveRecord();
                    RegisterRepositories();
                    RegisterServices();  
                    RegisterControllers();
                    RegisterComponents();
                }
```

I have done it by

```
 private void RegisterControllers()
        {
            try
            {
                _Container.Register(
                    AllTypes.Of<IController>()
                    .FromAssembly(typeof(HomeController).Assembly)
                    .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.Transient)
                    );
```

It works fine for all controllers with default constructors.
But, I have a controller (LoginController) with parameterzied construtor.

```
public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        private IUser _User;

        public LoginController(IUser objUser)
        {
            _User = objUser;
        }
```

When I tried to view it in browser (http://localhost:2011/Login), it gives me following error.

```
**No parameterless constructor defined for this object**
Stack Trace: 
[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +98
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +241
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +69
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +6
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +491

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'NAATEELib.Controllers.LoginController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +628
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +204
```

Please guide me. I do not want to modify .config (xml) files.
thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you forgot to use a Windsor controller factory (the stack trace shows DefaultControllerFactory).

Take a look at this [Windsor - ASP.NET MVC tutorial](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/mvc-tutorial-intro.md), in particular [part 2](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/mvc-tutorial-part-2-plugging-windsor-in.md).

EDIT: OP edited the question, code is already using MvcContrib's Windsor controller factory. Either the registrations are wrong (recommend using MvcContrib's RegisterControllers) or the controller factory isn't correctly installed.

Comment: Thaks Mauricio, but, i'm using MvcContrib.Castle.WindsorControllerFactory to initialize container.

Comment: I have revised my question. Can you please give me little more hint? why it's not using WindsorControllerFactory? and how can i add parameters while registering controllers? Thanks again.

Comment: You probably want to remove the `try-catch` around the initialization code - there's probably no valid reason for the initialization to fail, and it would probably help you diagnosing what's really the issue here.

Comment: @user153335: did you call SetControllerFactory? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbuilder.setcontrollerfactory.aspx

Comment: yes. in InitializeWindsor() method, I have called..                     ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MvcContrib.Castle.WindsorControllerFactory(_Container));

Comment: @user153335: ok, then are you calling `InitializeWindsor()` in Application_Startup?

Comment: yes. I'm calling InitializeWindsor() method in application_start of global.asax. The application is working fine for all controllers with default constructors. I'm facing issue only for controllers with parameterzied constructor. :)

Comment: @user153335: can you put a breakpoint on SetControllerFactory to make sure it's called? Also, do you have a component implementing IUser registered in the container? Are you sure LoginController is in the same assembly as HomeController?

Comment: @user153335: since you're already using MvcContrib, why not just use its RegisterControllers extension method? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896337/need-help-with-castle-windsor-as-an-asp-net-mvc-controllerfactory-please/968843#968843

Comment: Many Thanks Mauricio!!! i got it.. the problem was.. i was using old version (1.5.999.0) of MVCContrib.Castle.dll. It has WindsorControllerFactory, but, does not handle GetControllerInstance correctly. Hence i have written my own WindsorControllerFactory. since, newer version of MVCContrib does not contain WindsorControllerFactory.  Thanks again.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer Web page moved to https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/mvc-tutorial-part-2-plugging-windsor-in.md

Answer (score 0):

Below changes, I have done to get rid of this problem.

I have:

- Migrated to `System.Web.Mvc 3`
- Used `MVCContrib.Extras.3.0.51.0`
- Written `WindsorControllerFactory`, since, `MVCContrib 3` excluded it.
- Used `RegisterControllers` extension method of container

---

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{  
    private IWindsorContainer _container;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of the <see cref="WindsorControllerFactory"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="container">The Windsor container instance to use when creating controllers.</param>
    public WindsorControllerFactory(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
        }

        _container = container;
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext context, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, string.Format("The controller for path '{0}' could not be found or it does not implement IController.", context.HttpContext.Request.Path));
        }

        var controller = (IController)_container.Resolve(controllerType) as Controller;

        return controller;
    }

    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        var disposable = controller as IDisposable;

        if (disposable != null)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }

        _container.Release(controller);
    }
}
```

and in `Global.asax.cs`, to register controllers,

```
_Container.RegisterControllers(typeof(HomeController).Assembly);
```

Answer (score -1):

tugberk solution is great, but if you want a simple way, you can define a parameter less constructor for your `LoginController` and initialize it with default value like this:

```
public LoginController():this(new MyUser()) // MyUser is an implementation of IUser
{
}


public LoginController(IUser objUser)
{
     _User = objUser;
}
```

Comment: This couples the types, which is in direct opposition of IoC

Comment: See for example http://lostechies.com/chadmyers/2009/07/14/the-usual-result-of-poor-man-s-dependency-injection/